# How to add the scalar variables and store the result in another scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
declare @Maxamount int,
        @month varchar,
        @Duration int,
        @iReturn int

set @month = (select DATEPART(MM,start_date) from TC_Project_Referal where id_tc_projuser = @id_tc_projuser)
set @Duration = (select fixeddDuration from TC_Project_Referal where id_tc_projuser = @id_tc_projuser)

select @Maxamount = @month+@Duration-1
```

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.    i have more than 1 record in the database. data will be display based on the id. we can have mutiple records for the single id also .then how to

Comment: what error you have occured...

Comment: Can you state an actual question please?

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. i have more than 1 record in the database. data will be display based on the id. we can have mutiple records for the single id also .then how to

Answer (score 0):

use INTO.

```
select DATEPART(MM,start_date) **into** @month from TC_Project_Referal where id_tc_projuser = @id_tc_projuser;

select fixeddDuration **into** @Duration from TC_Project_Referal where id_tc_projuser = @id_tc_projuser;

select @Maxamount := @month+@Duration-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your inner query happens to return more than one row , you will get the following error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Ensure that queries return single record using TOP clause

```
declare @Maxamount int,
        @month varchar,
        @Duration int,
        @iReturn int

set @month = (select TOP 1 DATEPART(MM,start_date) from TC_Project_Referal where id_tc_projuser = @id_tc_projuser order by start_date)
set @Duration = (select TOP 1 fixeddDuration from TC_Project_Referal where id_tc_projuser = @id_tc_projuser order by id_tc_projuser )

select @Maxamount = @month+@Duration-1
```

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. i have more than 1 record in the database. data will be display based on the id. we can have mutiple records for the single id also .then how to display

Comment: what do you wanna display ?

Comment: i want to display more than 1 record

Comment: You want Maxamount to be displayed for multiple records ?